# url encoding to prevent xss attacking

Tags: java, html, xss

Below is the url im creating in the java program which is used to download file.

```
String servletPathURL = "/BookAppWebProject/download fileName="+fileName+".csv&fileFormat=vnd.ms-excel"+"&methodName=exportUsers&filePath="+tmpFilePath;
```

and in UI(jsp page) i am using iframe to bring popup window(which shows option for save & open the file from above url)and also set that url to iframe SRC attribute dynamically using script

```
jQuery(initialise_exportiframe);
function initialise_exportiframe() {
var flag ='<%= session.getAttribute("exportFlag") %>';
var exportURL ='<%= session.getAttribute("exportServletURL") %>';
if(flag == '1') {
    <% session.setAttribute("exportFlag", "0"); %>
    document.getElementById("exportFrame").src=exportURL;
}
   }

<iframe id="exportFrame" style="display: none" src="/IPSSWebProject/framework/skeletons/EnterprisePortalLAF/IPSS_blank.html"></iframe>
```

My concern is, I can see exact url in "viewsourcepage", which could leads to XSS attack. Can anyone tell me how to hide or encode this original url.

Comment: Where do the "fileName" and "tmpFilePath" come from? Your URL will be visible in the source anyway as the browser needs to access the URL and download the file - this fact in itself does not allow for a XSS attack.

Comment: @Andres. fileName is hardcoded in java program and I am creating file using File class like final File tmpFile = File.createTempFile(fileName, ".csv");
   writer = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
   writer.write(exportText);

   tmpFilePath = tmpFile.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: The URL generated in java program is dispalyed in ViewSourcePAge. I need to hide or encode that url in viewsourcepage.. or else is their anyothe way to handle it?

Comment: What ever you do, the browser needs to see that URL to fetch it. You might be able to obfuscate the URL a bit using Javascript on the client side but there is no way to hide it completely as the browser needs to know what to fetch. Do not make your security model depend on a URL not being known.